# Reformat data frame to long format keeping grouped columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reformat

Consider the following data frame:

```
set.seed(42)
ID <- c(1:6) 
OB <- c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2))
lat_start <- rnorm(6,42,2)
lon_start <- rnorm(6,12,2)
lat_stopp <- rnorm(6,42,2)
lon_stopp <- rnorm(6,12,2)
df <- data.frame(ID,OB,lat_start,lon_start,lat_stopp,lon_stopp)
```

I would like to reformat `df` to a long format, where each `ID` has a row for the start and stop coordinates. A simple `gather()` solution, e.g. `df_wrong <- gather(df,coords,val,lat_start:lon_stopp)` will obviously not work, as I need the lat/lon columns to stay grouped. I want the long data frame to look something like this:

```
   ID OB    SS      lat       lon
1   1  A start 44.74192 15.023040
2   1  A  stop 39.22228  7.119066
3   2  A start 40.87060 11.810680
4   2  A  stop 41.44242 14.640227
5   3  A start 42.72626 16.036850
6   3  A  stop 41.73336 11.386723
7   4  A start 43.26573 11.874570
8   4  A  stop 43.27190  8.437383
9   5  B start 42.80854 14.609740
10  5  B  stop 41.43149 11.656165
11  6  B start 41.78775 16.573290
12  6  B  stop 36.68709 14.429349
```

The `SS` column can of course be added later. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(ID, OB)) %>%
 separate(var, c("var1", "SS")) %>%
 spread(var1, val)

   ID OB    SS      lat       lon
1   1  A start 44.74192 15.023044
2   1  A stopp 39.22228  7.119066
3   2  A start 40.87060 11.810682
4   2  A stopp 41.44242 14.640227
5   3  A start 42.72626 16.036847
6   3  A stopp 41.73336 11.386723
7   4  A start 43.26573 11.874572
8   4  A stopp 43.27190  8.437383
9   5  B start 42.80854 14.609739
10  5  B stopp 41.43149 11.656165
11  6  B start 41.78775 16.573291
12  6  B stopp 36.68709 14.429349
```

Comment: `-c(ID, OB)` gives me `Error: Unknown columns A, A, A, A, A and ... `. I've substituted that for `lat_start:lon_stopp`, which works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could `unlist` and create a rearranged matrix.

```
d <- matrix(unlist(t(df[3:6])), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
setNames(data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(list(df$ID, as.character(df$OB)), 
                                 function(x) rep(x, each=2))), 
                    c("start", "stop"),
                    d), c(names(df)[1:3], "lat", "lon"))
#    ID OB lat_start      lat       lon
# 1   1  A     start 44.74192 15.023044
# 2   1  A      stop 39.22228  7.119066
# 3   2  A     start 40.87060 11.810682
# 4   2  A      stop 41.44242 14.640227
# 5   3  A     start 42.72626 16.036847
# 6   3  A      stop 41.73336 11.386723
# 7   4  A     start 43.26573 11.874572
# 8   4  A      stop 43.27190  8.437383
# 9   5  B     start 42.80854 14.609739
# 10  5  B      stop 41.43149 11.656165
# 11  6  B     start 41.78775 16.573291
# 12  6  B      stop 36.68709 14.429349
```

Comment: This can also be done using `reshape`: `reshape(df, idvar = c("ID", "OB"), varying = 3:6, direction = "long", sep = "_")`

Comment: @markus That makes it easier to code, it's much slower though.